# Differential Equation with a Singular point/singularity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

This is one problem from my problem sheet that I have no idea how to do because our lecturer (in my opinion) did a terrible job of explaining. I would really appreciate if you could help me understand what is going on here.

In lecture we defined the following differential equation:

$$y'=\frac{G(x,y)}{F(x,y)}$$

We assumed that $F,G$ vanish at point $(x_0,y_0)$. So we approximated the behavior of the diff. equation at point $(x_0,y_0)$ as:

$$y'=\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}$$

(I have no idea why we can just do that). Also, we defined a matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

Then we applied a invertible linear transformation to it:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \zeta \\ \eta\end{pmatrix}=D\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}d_{11} & d_{12} \\d_{21} &d_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} \iff \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=D^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} \zeta \\ \eta\end{pmatrix}$$

Our lecturer then said something about the eigenvalues of $A$ giving us information about the solutions.

How do I use this information to solve the problem I mentioned above. It seems to me that I am missing some crucial information

Can someone explain to me what these matrices are for? I don't see the goal/pupose of this whole exercise. Is this some standard mathematical procedure when it comes to dealing with singularities?

Edit: In case this question is incomprehensible or is missing some information/context please leave a comment.

Edit: I am still interested in any hints/suggestions you might have. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried reading the questions ?

Comment: @mercio I am not sure if I understand your comment but of course I have tried reading the questions. I understand a) and b) and I can calculate the eigenvalues, eigenvectors and the transformation matrix $D$ but I have no idea _why_ I am calculating them. I just don't see the connection to singular points/singularities of differential equations.

Comment: You did a change of variable from $(x,y)$ to $(\xi,\eta)$, so when you translate the differential equation (the relation between $x,y$ and $dy/dx$) in terms of those new variables, what do you get ? What's the corresponding relation between $\xi, \eta$ and $d\eta/d\xi$ ?

Comment: @mercio I am not sure. But since I have the following relationship: $$\begin{pmatrix} \zeta \\ \eta\end{pmatrix}=D\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}d_{11} & d_{12} \\d_{21} &d_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$$

I would guess that $$\zeta=d_{11}x+d_{12}y=\lambda_1 x \\ \eta=d_{21}x+d_{22}y=\lambda_2 y$$

since $d_{12}=d_{21}=0$

But why am I making this change of varibles in the first place?

Comment: $d_{11}x + d_{12}y$ is not $\lambda_1 x$. We want something about $\xi, \eta$, and $d\eta/d\xi$. What's $d\eta/d\xi$ in terms of the old variables ?

Comment: $D$ is not a diagonal matrix, $DAD^{-1}$ is.

Comment: @mercio I deleted my previous comments because I was getting tired and making silly mistakes. You asked for a relationship betwenn $\eta,\xi$. I have $$\begin{pmatrix}dx \\ dy\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}a &b \\ c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$$

short: $d\vec{x}=A\vec{x}$

I know that $\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix} \longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
 \xi \\\eta\end{pmatrix}=D\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix} \implies \vec{\xi}=D\vec{x} \implies \begin{pmatrix}d \xi \\d \eta\end{pmatrix}=D\begin{pmatrix}dx \\dy\end{pmatrix}$ Is that correct? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following remarks try to explain the philosophy behind this problem.

Seeing your differential equation I set up a "concomitant" first order ODE  for a vector-valued function $t\mapsto \bigl(x(t), \>y(t)\bigr)$ of an auxiliary "time" variable $t$, as follows:
$$\eqalign{\dot x&=x-Py\cr \dot y&=Px+Qy\cr}\tag{1}$$
The solutions $t\mapsto \bigl(x(t), \>y(t)\bigr)$ of this system can be considered as parametric representations of certain curves $\gamma$ in the $(x,y)$-plane. If such a curve is written as  graph of a function $f_\gamma: \>x\mapsto y(x)$ then
$$y'(x)={dy\over dx}={\dot y\over\dot x}={Px+Qy\over x-Py}\ ,$$
which shows that $f_\gamma$ satisfies the differential equation given at the outset.

The above serves as a motivation to investigate the linear system $(1)$ whose matrix is given by
$$A=\left[\matrix{1 &-P \cr P &Q\cr}\right]\ .$$
Systems of the kind $(1)$ are a prime paradigm in the theory of ODEs. Let it suffice for the moment that diagonalization of the matrix $A$ allows to "separate the unknown variables": In the coordinates $(\xi,\eta)$ corresponding to the "eigenbasis" of $A$ the system $(1)$ simply reads
$$\dot\xi=\lambda_1\>\xi,\qquad \dot\eta=\lambda_2\>\eta$$
and has the solutions
$$\xi(t)=C_1 e^{\lambda_1 t},\qquad \eta(t)=C_2e^{\lambda_2 t}\ .$$

In the case of your problem a non-negligible amount of calculation will result, which I hesitate to go into at the moment.

Comment: Awesome answer! Vielen Dank! Just a short follow up question. If I understand what you wrote correctly, then in order to solve the system (1) I need to diagonalize $A$ which is equivalent to separating my variables. Why then, am I changing variables from $x,y$ to $\eta,\xi$? I don't see the motivation behind that.